# c++ introduction: self study

Tags: c++

I got help for  my program for the following code. I is working, thank you to 'paxdiablo'. It is still showing the '\' character in the result. How can I fix it? (not sure how to reply 'paxdiablo' to sya thanks.

```
if (strchr (",.();:-\"&?%$![]^@~`{}_<>/#*_+=", curChar) != NULL)//new change
{
   paragraph.erase(subscript, 1);
   numWords-=1;
}
else 
   subscript+=1;

}
```

Comment: sorry for the spelling mistakes.  I tried adding the '\' to the chars, did not work.

Comment: Maybe you should post more of your code, there's no way I can understand this.

Comment: Please read the SQ FAQ, here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 5):

Not a C expert but try escaping the \

```
if (strchr ("\\,.();:-\"&?%$![]^@~`{}_<>/#*_+=", curChar) != NULL)//new change
```

Answer (score 2):

See how the string that you match against has `\"` in it?

That is an escape sequence. It tells the C++ compiler, "I want the `"` symbol to be in this string literal". You have to say this in this special way because normally, `"` marks the end of the string.

The `\` character is special, because it starts all of these escape sequences. So if you want it to appear in the string, you have to use an escape sequence for that, too. Otherwise, the compiler thinks you are starting some other escape sequence.

The escape sequence for `\` is, oddly enough, `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove '\' as well, you want to do this:

```
if (strchr (",.();:-\\\"&?%$![]^@~`{}_<>/#*_+=", curChar) != NULL)
```

The reason being the original line had `\"` which is really escaping the `"`. To add an actual `\` you need to do `\\` to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape character (it's escaping the "). Add `\\` to your characters string and it should work.

```
if (strchr (",.();:-\"&?%$![]^@~`{}_<>/#*_+=\\", curChar) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping it: `\\` instead of just `\`